# 'Can't set headers after they are sent.' Express.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, express.js, header

Estou tentando enviar a variável **'nome'** para o client-side, mas só esta funcionando quando eu executo um `respons.end()` quando eu uso dois, retorna esse erro:

```
> 'Can't set headers after they are sent.'
```

***Server***

```
router.get('/:eventnick', function(req, res, next){
  EventData.findOne({eventnick: req.params.username}, function(err, eventInfos){
    var name = eventInfos.name;//0
    res.render('event/eventpage/eventpage', {title: 'teste| '+ name},);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(name));
  });
});
```

***Client***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  var splitUrl = url.split('/');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'/event/'+splitUrl[4],
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro consiste porque você esta tentando enviar duas vezes informação para o cliente como resposta.

Após responder ao cliente o cabeçalho `HEADER` é enviado... não é possível sobrescrever ou enviar outro.

Se você está "ouvindo" a resposta e deseja receber um `JSON`, apenas responda no formato `JSON`:

**Server**:

```
router.get('/:eventnick', function(req, res, next){
    EventData.findOne({eventnick: req.params.username}, function(err, eventInfos){
        var name = eventInfos.name;//0
        res.json(JSON.stringify(name));
    });
});
```

Se você esta tentado "mesclar" este `JSON` e devolver um fragmento `HTML` deverá fazer isto antes da resposta possivelmente um "parse", "replace" ou alguma função do seu framework de renderização e então devolver apenas com:

```
res.render(seu_fragmento_aqui)
```

Comment: No caso eu nao poderia usar os dois?Os dois eu digo os dois res.

Comment: No caso, estou tentando enviar a variavel e renderizar!

Comment: Isso não é possível! Após usar um ou outro você estará enviando uma resposta, não é possível enviar duas resposta para o mesmo pedido!