# É possível adicionar dados de um script em node pra o html?

Tags: node.js

Eu sou bastante iniciante no âmbito do *node.js*, mas queria na humildade, entender o porquê de um código só aparecer no console.log do node e não poder armazenar em alguma variável para que eu possa manipulá-la no html com javascript cru, já que só de eu abrir um arquivo html com node importado, o console diz que o comando *require* não foi definido.

Esta é a API que estou a utilizar:
https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api

```
    var http = require('http');

    const translate = require('google-translate-api');

    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var url = req.url;


    translate('We did it!', {to: 'pt'}).then(res => {
      console.log(res.text);
    //=> I speak English
    console.log(res.from.language.iso);
    //=> nl



    }).catch(err => {
     console.error(err);
    });



    });

     server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

     console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Porém, estou perdido de como utilizar no html :(
Por favor, alguém me ajuda ou me dá alguma alternativa que possa usar pls.

Comment: Vixi... difícil de entender sua pergunta. Node roda no back-end o script é executado e armazenado em memória, o javascript do HTML é executado no front-end (no cliente/navegador). Algumas bibliotecas (módulos) de Node podem ser executadas no front-end nativamente ou com uso de Browserify desde que, sejam projetadas para tal ou executem funções e recursos suportados por ambos os ambientes. Você deseja passar um objeto javascript do Node para o front-end?

Comment: A função **"require()"** é um dos métodos de importação de Node (loader), onde o script busca (importa) bibliotecas ou mesmo outros scripts (não necessariamente "módulos"). Versões mais recentes de Node bem como módulos que seguem um padrão mais recente usam **"import"**. Você pode pegar a chamada de seu **js** pela rota, modificá-lo (uma vez que é somente texto) e devolver um script customizado, existem prós e contras neste "método". Eu recomendaria que você edita-se sua pergunta. Não esta clara o suficiente para apresentar uma resposta.

Comment: Tipo, a pergunta mais direta seria... **Teria como utilizar algum dado do node.js em uma página html (_clientside_), ou de nenhuma forma ?** 
Porque eu só quero esse dado que o objeto tem, que seria uma string contendo uma tradução...

Comment: Você pode buscar este dado usando `REST` fazendo uma requisição com `AJAX` ou `Fetch` ... você pode usar `JSON.stringy()` para tornar este dado em uma `{String}` e acomodar ao seu `HTML` para devolver ao usuário e buscar no `DOM` este dado simplesmente fazendo `JSON.parse()` ou pode modificar seu `javascript` para devolver este dado. Existem várias formas, você deves apenas pensar na "menos custosa" e que atenda suas necessidades. Como achas que deve ser?

Comment: Como você "abastece" a função de traduzir com uma `{String}`? Esta enviando esta `{String}` via `POST` para o servidor? Se for este o caso, isto é `REST`...basta apenas devolver o resultado. É isso que procuras?

Comment: Quando uma requisição é feita ao servidor ele pode devolver apenas uma resposta por vez. Não é possível devolver várias resposta, apenas a primeira é enviada e fecha a conexão. Então ou você utiliza `REST` para buscar a tradução por uma "rota de requisição" ou faz um parse em seu "documento" para adicionar esta informação ao documento ou ainda podes fazer um parse no seu arquivo javascript para devolver este objecto no próprio `js` e utilizá-lo no front-end.

Comment: Possivelmente relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269121/cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-express-js/269134#269134

Comment: Lauro, muito obrigado pela paciência. É... Eu só queria realmente apenas fazer da forma mais simples. Por exemplo, eu nem to fazendo isso profissionalmente, foi um teste (_Sou bem iniciante com node.js_), então o que queria de verdade era "*apenas*" pegar o dado de determinado objeto e mostrar no html, por teste mesmo. Tipo, esse meu código que disponibilizei na pergunta foi feito com a intenção apenas de teste, se você vê, a entrada é predefinida:  
translate('We did it!', {to: 'pt'}), o que eu queria era guardar esse dado de saída em uma variável e de alguma forma enviar no html...

Comment: Eu queria fazer de uma forma tão simples como, por exemplo: "<p><?php $varContendoSaidaTraduzida ?> </p>"... O que eu quero fazer é tão simples, mas como não tenho tanto conhecimento com node.js está se tornando uma dor de cabeça.(*E não tem nada a ver com php, só disse mais ou menos a minha intenção*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já mencionado, o node roda server-side, logo ele não irá rodar dentro de uma html client-side. Pense que as variáveis do Node estão em um contexto separado do javascript que irá rodar no front. Como já falaram, você teria que fazer uma requisição para o seu server para buscar os dados do lado do node. Ou também, injetar as variáveis no HTML e então enviar para o client.

Pensando no seu comentário sobre querer usar como `"<p><?php $varContendoSaidaTraduzida ?> </p>"...`, acho que o mais perto disso seria usar uma Template Engine.

A template engine irá permitir que você introduza pedaços de código no meio da sua HTML. Como por exemplo, utilizando EJS:

```html
<body>
  <h1> Hello world! <%= message %> </h1>
</body>
```

Baseado no que você já tem, vou te dar um exemplo usando template engine e também fazendo uma chamada ao node(server) com Fetch. É bem simples, na verdade. O primeiro passo para você, seria escutar pelas requisições e devolver um html:

```js
var http = require('http');
const translate = require('google-translate-api');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     var url = req.url;
     //Escutando em localhost:1337/translate
     if(url ==='/translate'){
         translate('We did it!', {to: 'pt'}).then(response => {
             var translated = response.text;
             res.write('<h1>'+translated+'<h1>');
             res.end(); //end the response
         }).catch(err => {
             console.error(err);
         });
     }else{
         res.write('<h1>Not found!<h1>');
         res.end(); //end the response
     }
});
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Isso irá fazer com que você veja a mensagem traduzida quando acessar pelo navegador o localhost:1337/translate.

Agora o que precisamos fazer é instalar a template engine e criar um HTML para renderizar assim que recebermos um request, e então envia-lo de volta.

**Primeiro**, instale o EJS: `npm install ejs`

Agora crie um arquivo chamado `home.ejs` no mesmo nível do seu app.js (ou o nome que tiver dado para o seu servidor node), com o seguinte código:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Tradutor </h1>
  <p> <%= message %> </p>
  <p> <%= translation %> </p>
  <p id='test'></p>
</body>
<script>
  //chamada para /fetchdata do client-side para o server-side
  fetch('/fetchdata').then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.example;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
</script>
```

Agora, finalmente, mude seu app.js para o seguinte:

```js
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

const translate = require('google-translate-api');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var url = req.url;

    //chamada para root
    if(url ==='/'){
      res.write('<h1>Welcome!</h1>');
      res.end();
    }
    //chamada para /translate
    else if(url ==='/translate'){
       translate('We did it!', {to: 'pt'}).then(response => {
           var translated = response.text;
           //ler o arquivo home.ejs
           var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/home.ejs', 'utf8');
           //json para injetar na view
           var json = {
             message: 'Olá!',
             translation: translated
           }
           //injetar json e rendizar com ejs (template engine)
           var htmlRenderizado = ejs.render(html, json);
           //envia para o client
           res.write(htmlRenderizado);
           res.end();
         }).catch(err => {
           console.error(err);
         });
     }
     //chamada para /fetchdata
     else if(url === '/fetchdata'){
       var data = {
         example: 'Data from fetch!'
       }
       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
       res.end();
     }
     else{
        res.write('<h1>Not found!<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
     }
});
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Agora você tem um exemplo de como utilizar uma Template Engine e também de como fazer uma requisição do html para o node! Aconselho fortemente a dar uma olhada no Expressjs, ele irá facilitar muito o uso das rotas (que nesse exemplo está bem simplificado).